# how to remove some elements from list depends upon some criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is my first question here. Hope some of you will help.

I have two list.

```
    list1 = ['sign','SIGN','siGN','DESIGN','design','deSIGn','xxdesignxx', 
            'xxdesign', 'xxdesignxx', '.sign.', 'sign.', 'sign.',
            'sign.', 'xxsignxx', 'xxsign', 'xxsignxx','abc','def']
    list2 = ['sign']
```

i want output as  :

```
list1 = ['DESIGN','design','deSIGn','xxdesignxx', 
        'xxdesign', 'xxdesignxx','xxsignxx', 'xxsign', 
        'xxsignxx']
```

simply i want to remove all "sign" (uppercase/lowercase/combination of both/prefix,suffix by any ".")

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: But `sign.`, `.sign` and `.sign.` all contain `sign` *and* are longer than `sign`, so they match your condition. Perhaps you want to add a condition `and '.' not in i`?

Comment: all variations of "sign" can be found using either `.upper` or `.lower` method of string. For the other cases (.sign, sign.) you will either need regular expressions or explicity exclude them.

Comment: @00 i have edited the question. Can you please help me out

Comment: @nomansland008 i have edited the question. Can you please help me out

Comment: Why is `list2` a one-element list? Do you intend for it to have more elements, and if so, what would the input and the intended output look like? If not, a single string would suffice, instead of a list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
list1 = ['sign','SIGN','siGN','design', 'design', 'design', 
         'xxdesignxx', 'xxdesign', 'xxdesignxx', '.sign.', 'sign.', 
         'sign.', 'sign.', 'xxsignxx', 'xxsign', 'xxsignxx']
list2 = ['sign']

res = [i for i in list1 if i.lower().strip('.') not in list2[0]]
print(res)
```

Output:-

```
['design', 'design', 'design', 'xxdesignxx', 'xxdesign', 'xxdesignxx', 'xxsignxx', 'xxsign', 'xxsignxx']
```

---

Answer for edited question

```
list1 = ['sign','SIGN','siGN','DESIGN','design','deSIGn','xxdesignxx', 
         'xxdesign', 'xxdesignxx', '.sign.', 'sign.', 'sign.',
         'sign.', 'xxsignxx', 'xxsign', 'xxsignxx','abc','def']
list2 = ['sign']

res = [i for i in list1 if list2[0] in i.lower() and i.lower().strip('.') not in list2[0]]
print(res)
```

Output:-

```
['DESIGN', 'design', 'deSIGn', 'xxdesignxx', 'xxdesign', 'xxdesignxx', 'xxsignxx', 'xxsign', 'xxsignxx']
```

Comment: Unfortunately, with the edit done by the OP after this answer was posted, this answer would include the strings `'abc'` and `'def'`, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: I don't think the edit works in general, since it explicity uses the string `'sign'`; that will likely not work as intended if `list2` changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `filter()` function to filter certain values from a list instead of list comprehension. Other than that, you just need to put all elements in the same upper/lowercase format and filter out periods.

```
list(filter(lambda x: 'sign' != ''.join([i for i in x if i.isalpha()]).lower(), list1))
```

```
['design',
 'design',
 'design',
 'xxdesignxx',
 'xxdesign',
 'xxdesignxx',
 'xxsignxx',
 'xxsign',
 'xxsignxx']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, `^(\.|)` startswith `.` or `empty` followed by `sign`

```
import re

search_ = re.compile("^(\.|)sign", re.IGNORECASE)

[x for x in list1 if not search_.search(x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use `str.strip()` to strip off any `'.'`, then compare:

```
list1 = ['sign','SIGN','siGN','DESIGN','design','deSIGn','xxdesignxx', 
        'xxdesign', 'xxdesignxx', '.sign.', 'sign.', 'sign.',
        'sign.', 'xxsignxx', 'xxsign', 'xxsignxx','abc','def']

list2 = ['sign']

list1 = [w for w in list1 if len(list2[0]) < len(w.strip('.'))]

print(list1)
```

Output:

```
['DESIGN', 'design', 'deSIGn', 'xxdesignxx', 'xxdesign', 'xxdesignxx', 'xxsignxx', 'xxsign', 'xxsignxx']
```

Answer (score -2):

If i did not understand wrong u want to delete sign word with punctuations too.

```
s.translate(None, string.punctuation)
```

s is string u have. Maybe this will help.

For higher python versions

```
s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
```

Comment: Have you tried the above code ? ``'sign.'.translate(None, "")`` >> ``TypeError translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)``

Comment: @Sushanth i guess u using higher version of python then me. I edit. U can check it for higher version solution

Comment: I don't know when it changes exactly. U have the research tools like me. U can check it easily. I don't understand WHAT ARE U LOOKING FOR in StackOverflow. We are here to help each other. The reason is not giving exact solution.